# Alamofire places the application API at the beginning of url rather than end of it

Tags: swift, alamofire, openweathermap

I'm building a simple weather application, nothing complicated, I just need to get the JSON from Open Weather Map based on user location. This is a correct URL structure to get the JSON from WOM `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52.516221&lon=13.408363&appid=e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713`

However, this is what my swift code / Alamofire gives me `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713&lat=52.516221&long=13.408363`
so it places the `apiid=***` at the beginning of url rather than end of it.

This is my code.

```
 let WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
 let APP_ID = "e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713"

  func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters : [String : String]) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess   {
            print ("Everything is fine")
            print (   Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters))
            let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            print (weatherJSON)
        }
        else {
            print ("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            self.cityLabel.text = "Connection issues"
        }
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
        if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            let latitude = "52.516221"
            let longitude = "13.408363"
            let params : [String : String] = ["lat" : latitude, "long" : longitude, "appid" : APP_ID]

            getWeatherData(url : WEATHER_URL, parameters : params)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of params in REST APIs doesn't matter.

Problem with your code is you are passing the wrong parameter name. `long` should be `lon`.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713&lat=52.516221&lon=13.408363

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52.516221&lon=13.408363&appid=e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713

Above Both requests will give you same results.

Try this. I just changed parameter 'long' to `lon`.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let latitude = "52.516221"
        let longitude = "13.408363"
        let params : [String : String] = ["lat" : latitude, "lon" : longitude, "appid" : APP_ID]

        getWeatherData(url : WEATHER_URL, parameters : params)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to cry now not seeing such a small issue, thanks mate